# Melting temperature and electronegativity trends in transition metals

Tags: transition-metals, periodic-trends, melting-point, electronegativity

So I know that generally the melting temperature increases across the row (let's look at just the first row for now) but what are the deviations? And why do they occur? I've looked everywhere online and can't find a clear answer to this.

Comment: I read that one, they say that Cr and Mn have ½ full 3d sub-shells and are therefore more stable but I can't understand how that would lead them to have a lower melting temperature